# OAuth2 - Securing multiple webservices' APIs with one token

Tags: web-services, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have three web services exposing their APIs.

Internally they are running on different ports but on the same server.
Then I have a nginx instance mapping those services to "api.domain.com", so that they are accessible from the web.

Now I need to secure this services, and I was thinking about OAuth2.
Unfortunatly I have no experience with OAuth2 so I'd like to know if there's a way to use one access token for all three webservices without requiring a different auth for each service.

What I want to make is to allow a consumer to be able to get the authorization once and then access all services under api.domain.com (that's just a reverse proxy forwarding request to our internal services).

Then I'd need to create a simple interface to perform certain operations on those services.
It would allow my users to login with their account info, of course this interface would be a consumer itself for those services, can I skip the authorization part and allow this app to work on the behalf of the user by just making it login? It will run on the same server with services.

Can I do this with OAuth2 or am I better looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this irrespective of whether you use OAuth or not.

You can have a reverse proxy that sits in front of your services/apps that requires Authentication.  If the request is unauthenitcated it redirects to what ever authentication mechanism is being used. Once that happens it sets an authenticated request header that contains the user name and the requests are passed on to whatever rules are configured.

Am not sure of nginx but I have used apache modules like mod_authnz_ldap, mod_auth_cas to make sure the requests passing through it are authenticated. This is the sample of my apache config that uses CAS for authentication and checks users LDAP group for authorization (user should belong to developers group)

```
# a2enmod
#    proxy_http
#    auth_cas
#    authnz_ldap

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servername

    LogLevel debug

    CASVersion 2
    CASDebug On 
    CASValidateServer Off
    CASLoginURL cas <loginurl>
    CASValidateURL <casvalidateurl>

    <Location />
        AuthType CAS

        AuthLDAPUrl ldap
        AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
        AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off

        Require valid-user
        Require ldap-group cn=developers,ou=Groups,dc=company,dc=com
        Satisfy All
    </Location>  

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Whether Oauth is a good choice for you really depends on your use case. From what I see, you don't really require that, but I don't have sufficient information either.

Comment: Just found that its a pretty old question, but leaving the answer here in case it helps someone looking at the question (and I had typed it out already).